# How can I make my character jump around when I move it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, move

I want to make a rabbit first person simulator, so I need to make every time my character moves, jumps, I try to do it like this:

```
if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") > 0)

  transform.position += new Vector3(transform.forward.x, 2f, transform.forward.z) * 2 * Time.deltaTime;
```

It works, but the problem is that when colliding with another element, the character slides up and ends up on top of the object.

I leave a gif to understand what happens:

[image]

Comment: I think we need more context. It seems like your code contains only "Jump up" behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Raycast` on your forward movement to check if you hit anything. if it returns nothing then you can make a move to forward. ([Take a look here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html))

```
using UnityEngine;

// C# example.

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float maxDetectionDistance = 1;
    void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        var isHit = Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit, maxDetectionDistance);
        // Does the ray intersect any objects excluding the player layer
        if (!isHit)
        {
            if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") > 0)
            {
                // your movement function
                transform.position += new Vector3(transform.forward.x, 2f, transform.forward.z) * 2 * Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * hit.distance, Color.yellow);
            Debug.Log("Did Hit");

        }
    }
}
```